# Sublime Text 3 adds spaces after saving file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a problem with Sublime Text 3 when I saving file with Python syntax. The spaces near to the operators are add automatically.
For example:
I type: *print(a," ",b+c)* and after saving file it will be: *print(a, " ", b + c)*
I try change settings but I don't know what does spaces after CTRL+S. I want white spaces but I don't want auto adding spaces in places where I don't type spaces.

My settings file:

```
    {
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "auto_complete": false,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
    "auto_match_enabled": true,
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "caret_style": "solid",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/ayu/ayu-dark.tmTheme",
    "detect_indentation": true,
    "draw_indent_guides": true,
    "draw_minimap_border": true,
    "enable_telemetry": false,
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "folder_exclude_patterns":
    [
        ".svn",
        ".git",
        ".hg",
        "CVS",
        "*.DS_Store",
        "*.pyc",
        "pycache"
    ],
    "font_face": "Liberation Mono",
    "font_options":
    [
        "subpixel_antialias",
        "no_round"
    ],
    "font_size": 14,
    "highlight_line": false,
    "highlight_modified_tabs": false,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_active",
        "draw_normal"
    ],
    "indent_to_bracket": true,
    "line_padding_bottom": 0,
    "line_padding_top": 0,
    "match_brackets": true,
    "match_brackets_angle": false,
    "match_brackets_braces": true,
    "match_brackets_content": true,
    "match_brackets_square": true,
    "new_window_settings":
    {
        "hide_open_files": true,
        "show_tabs": true,
        "side_bar_visible": true,
        "status_bar_visible": true
    },
    "pep8_max_line_length": 79,
    "preview_on_click": false,
    "rulers":
    [
        79
    ],
    "shift_tab_unindent": true,
    "show_panel_on_build": false,
    "soda_classic_tabs": true,
    "soda_folder_icons": false,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "theme": "ayu-dark.sublime-theme",
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "use_simple_full_screen": true,
    "vintage_start_in_command_mode": false,
    "wide_caret": true,
    "word_wrap": true,
    "wrap_width": 80,
    "material_theme_accent_graphite": true ,
    "material_theme_compact_sidebar": true,
    "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.sublime-workspace"],
}
```

Syntax-settings file:

```
    // These settings override both User and Default settings for the Python syntax
{
    "draw_white_space": "all",
    "auto_indent": true,
    "rulers": [79],
    "smart_indent": true,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "trim_automatic_white_space": true,
    "use_tab_stops": true,
    "word_wrap": true,
    "wrap_width": 80
}
```

Comment: You have installed a third party package that re-formats your code on save; Sublime doesn't do this otherwise. The list of packages you have installed is in the Package Control settings, so if you post that we can probably narrow it down for you.

Comment: I know now that was Anaconda. You know maybe how can I still have a autoformatting but without adding spaces? If I change "auto_formatting": true to false I haven't any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It was a Anaconda plugin.
You must set the following flag in the user's settings of this plugin:

```
"auto_formatting": true,
"autoformat_ignore":
    [
        "E309",
        "E501",
        "E221",
        "E222",
        "E223",
        "E225",
        "E226",
        "E227",
        "E228",
        "E231"
    ]
```

Comment: PEP 8 standards are there for a reason, they make code more readable. Try to follow 90 % of all standards, and be sure also to read PEP 8 and why python follows those standards.